# Alignment Issue of Text for Buttons CSS

Tags: html, css, joomla

As you can see the text on the images are not aligning correctly I have tried everything changing margin top of the css and I cannot get the text to float properly on the images can someone have a look at the css to see what may be the problem. It's the foot conditions menu that is the issue.

http://indigo.websitewelcome.com/~birchpodiatry/our-doctors

How to change the tag below as suggested by alex k in joomla 3.3?

Comment: adding a code chunk from codepen or jsfiddle here for review will help future users should your site link dry up.

Answer (score 1):

Your using a block element within an inline element, simply change

```
   <div class="image-title">Bunions</div>
</span>
```

to

```
   <span class="image-title">Bunions</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Yes, right click the element in your browser -> Inspect and change div to span to see

Comment: K just tryin to find it where it is in jooomla grrr

Comment: K do you no how I put this change into joomla at all

Comment: No idea, you could add `.image-title {display:inline;}` to the css or in the page in a `<style>` tag